# Deparse an R expression while preserving the comments

Tags: r, parsing

l'd like to convert an R expression into text.

I know you can use `deparse()` to do that. However, I need to keep the comments.

e.g.

```
deparse(substitute(
  {
    # comment
    5*5
  })
)
[1] "{"         "    5 * 5" "}" 
But I want...
[1] "{"         "    # comment" "    5 * 5" "}"
```

If there is anyway to convert an expression into text while preserving the comments I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `srcref` attribute that is available when R code is parsed:

```
deparse_with_comments <- function(e){
  e <- substitute(e)
  srcref <- attr(e, "srcref")
  sr <- srcref[[1]]
  sr[c(3,4,6,8)] <- srcref[[length(srcref)]][c(3,4,6,8)]
  sr
}
deparse_with_comments(
  {
    # comment
    5*5
  }
)
```

Comment: Can you please add a description for what the `c(3,4,6,8)` is doing here? How did you arrive at those particular numbers?