# How to convert expressions to character while keeping formatting in R

Tags: r

Is is possible to write a function that receives an expression and converts this expression to a character vector while keeping the formatting?

The last part (keeping the formatting) is the complicated part and I am not sure this is actually possible as the parser will have already parsed the expressions before calling the function.

Without keeping the formatting, I can do:

```
my_fun <- function(expr) {
  deparse(substitute(expr))
}

x <- my_fun({
  a <- 1+1
  # a comment
  if (a > 1) print("foo")
  if (a < 1) {
    print("foo",
      "bar");
  }
})
```

Resulting in:

```
> writeLines(x)
{
    a <- 1 + 1
    if (a > 1) 
        print("foo")
    if (a < 1) {
        print("foo", "bar")
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the code is reformatted using `deparse` and the comments are removed. I would like the output to be:

```
> writeLines(x)
{
  a <- 1+1
  # a comment
  if (a > 1) print("foo")
  if (a < 1) {
    print("foo",
      "bar");
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770385/deparse-an-r-expression-while-preserving-the-comments